# java: for-each not applicable to expression type required: array or java.lang.Iterable found: org.json.JSONArray

Tags: java, json

Here I want to implement a code to map input JSON data to the structure that user defines.
here is my code down below

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JsonMappingExample {
    private static final String FILE_PATH = "data.json";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Read JSON file
        JSONArray jsonData = readJsonArrayFromFile(FILE_PATH);

        // Make an instance from JsonMapping
        JsonMapping mapper = new JsonMapping();

        // Call mapping function
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = readDataFromJson(jsonData, mapper);

        // Apply post-processing
        results = postProcessing(results);

        // Print results
        results.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static JSONArray readJsonArrayFromFile(String filePath) {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath)) {
            JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(fis);
            return new JSONArray(tokener);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static List<Map<String, Object>> readDataFromJson(JSONArray json_data, JsonMapping mapping) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Object obj : json_data) {
            JSONObject item = (JSONObject) obj;
            Map<String, Object> mappedItem = new HashMap<>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Object>> entry : mapping.field_mapping.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                Map<String, Object> value = entry.getValue();
                if (item.has(key)) {
                    try {
                        String targetField = (String) value.get("target_field");
                        Object data = item.get(key);
                        mappedItem.put(targetField, data);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.printf("Error: Cannot convert %s%n", key);
                        mappedItem.put((String) value.get("target_field"), null);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.printf("Warning: Field '%s' not found in %s%n", key, item);
                }
            }
            result.add(mappedItem);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static List<Map<String, Object>> postProcessing(List<Map<String, Object>> results) {
        for (Map<String, Object> item : results) {
            try {
                String fullName = (String) item.get("firstName");
                String[] names = fullName.split(" ");
                item.put("firstName", names[0]);
                if (names.length > 1) {
                    item.put("lastName", names[1]);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.printf("Error: Field lastName can not be retrieved from Name (%s)%n", item.get("firstName"));
                item.put("lastName", null);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}

class JsonMapping {
    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> field_mapping;

    public JsonMapping() {
        field_mapping = new HashMap<>();
        field_mapping.put("id", Map.of("target_field", "employeeId", "data_type", int.class));
        field_mapping.put("name", Map.of("target_field", "firstName", "data_type", String.class));
        field_mapping.put("externalSystemProp1", Map.of("target_field", "age", "data_type", int.class));
    }
}
```

And here is my error

```
47:27
java: for-each not applicable to expression type
  required: array or java.lang.Iterable
  found:    org.json.JSONArray
```

the error is exactly in line 47 on json_data which is a JSONArray and it can not be treated. how should I fix this problem ?
I tried some ways to fix it but it didn't work for me. please help if you know what should I do with my code

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

for JSONArray I usualy just use traditional for loop like this.

```java
for(int i = 0; i<json_data.length(); i++){
    JSONObject item = json_data.getJSONObject(i);
    // the rest of the logic here
}
```

The docs says it implements iterable though.https://javadoc.io/doc/org.json/json/latest/org/json/JSONArray.html